# Access my model from foreverb daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code on a foreverb daemon to access my Availability model. but I always get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Availability
```

Here is my daemon:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'forever'
require 'mongoid'

Forever.run do

  every 10.seconds do
    @classes = Availability.where(:availability_date.gt => Time.now.utc + 1.hours).to_a
    puts @classes.count
  end

end
```

Thanks for your help.

Note: I'm using rails3 and mongoid.

UPDATED CODE

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'forever'
require 'mongoid'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

Forever.run do

  every 10.seconds do
        @classes = Availability.where(:availability_date.gt => Time.now.utc + 1.hours).to_a
        puts @classes.count
  end

end
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

user/classes_notification.rb; tail -f -n 150 user/sample.log;

```
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/config/environment (LoadError)
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from user/classes_notification.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE

---

[image: SCRIPT]
[image: ENVIRONMENT FILE]

UPDATE PATH

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'forever'
require 'mongoid'

# Load Rails
#ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV[0] || 'development'

require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment', __FILE__)

Forever.run do

  every 10.seconds do
        @classes = Availability.where(:availability_date.gt => Time.now.utc + 1.hours).to_a
        puts @classes.count
  end

end
```

Now I'm getting this eror:

```
script/user/classes_notification.rb; tail -f -n 150 script/user/sample.log;

WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      thor (>= 0.15.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated multi_json 1.10.1, but your Gemfile requires multi_json 1.8.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from script/user/classes_notification.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy load `Rails` env just add to top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```

Worked this simple 3 lines script in `Rails.root` dir.

[`Another examples`](https://gist.github.com/zachwaugh/521133)

Comment: thanks, I update my code but now I'm getting another error, Would you help me please

Comment: @Jean where your `Rails` app? looks like in `/Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/` no such Rails app.

Comment: I just upload two files of my path

Comment: @Jean and where your script placed?

Comment: script/user/classes_notification.rb, but I think the problem is the environment file, because ruby is trying to upload /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/config/environment instead of /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/environment

Comment: your structure files wrong, i noticed in answer about where script should be placed for right work, you should fix path to `config/environment` this fix problem.

Comment: I fixed the path, but now I getting an error on a gem that I don't understand what I have to do

Comment: script/user/classes_notification.rb; tail -f -n 150 script/user/sample.log; 

I need to send emails using the Availability records, but right now I can't even reach the Availability line

Comment: try this `bundle exec ./script/user/classes_notification.rb` and you script should be executed.